# Using accessors and mutators in Laravel json responses

Tags: php, json, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm making an API that produces a json response instead of doing `View::make('foo', compact('bar'))`.

**With blade templating**

My controller simply returns the Eloquent model for `Users`:

```
public function index()
{
    return User::all();
}
protected function getFooAttribute()
{
    return 'bar';
}
```

And my view will be able to use it, along with the `foo` attribute (which isn't a field in the user's table).

```
@foreach($users as $user)
<p>{{$user->name}} {{$user->foo}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**With Angular JS + json response**

However, now that I'm not using blade but rather grabbing the `json` and displaying it with Angular JS I'm not able to do this:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.name}} {{user.foo}}</p>
```

Is there a way to cleanly pack the json response such that I have:

```
[{"name": "John", "foo": "bar"}, ...]
```

Warning: I've never built an API before and I've only started programming/web dev last December. This is my attempt:

```
public function index()
{
  $response = User::all();
  foreach($response as $r)
  {
    $r->foo = $r->foo;
  }

  return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yeah there is, example:

```
return Response::json([User:all()], 200);
```

Usually you want more than that though..

```
return Response::json([
    'error' => false,
    'data' => User:all()
], 200);
```

`200` is the HTTP Status Code.

To include the attributes you need to specify these attributes to automatically append onto the response in your model.

```
protected $appends = array('foo');

public function getFooAttribute()
{
    return 'bar';    
}
```

Comment: That's weird, I'm getting an empty response `[{}]` from both examples.  SO won't let me fix your typos (`User::all()`). I've tried adding `$appends` and that seems to have fixed it with my code not working with `Response::json()` still.

Comment: Edit: Yes there is. Simply calling 'setAttribute' on the model and passing the return of the accessor works. Original Comment: Is there a way to only include the accessor only when needed, such as how loading of relationships works? I might need to data the accessor fetches on the front end in one place, but not another.